# Scope of exported variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a command I execute in the bash which requires an environment variable. If I call it like this, everything works fine:

```
export MYVAR=value & my_first_command
```

But now I want to pipe the result to a second command, which requires the same environment variable. I tried this one:

```
export MYVAR=value & my_first_command | my_second_command
```

In that case, `MYVAR` seems not to be set for `my_second_command`. What's the correct syntax to make `MYVAR` available to `my_second_command` too?

Comment: export should make MYVAR avaliable to all subprocess. FWIW, you have a typo, try `export MYVAR=value && my_first_command` to execute `my_first_command` if the previous command was successful.

Comment: I don't even understand how the first attempt can work. Using `&`, the variable ought to be exported in its do-nothing subshell only, and not to `my_first_command`.

Comment: what's wrong with `export MYVAR=value ; my_first_command ; my_second_command` ?

Comment: @slayedbylucifer In this case, I think its expected to work. As it just sequence of commands, where ';' acts as cmd-seperator. With '|' it won't work as per original problem statement above

Comment: `Scope` isn't quite the right concept here. That would imply that `MYVAR` isn't defined in the child, but that it could then somehow look up to the parent to see if `MYVAR` is defined there. Instead, the child is given its own copy of `MYVAR` when it begins, which is not affected even if the parent changes its value of `MYVAR` while the child is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` is incorrect and should be `;` instead.

Using `&` is syntactically valid, and runs a command in the background; but running `export` as a background task makes no sense at all.